# how to do rigidbody movement relative to player rotation in unity c#?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

in my game the player is to walk around a sphere, I'm using rigidbody to apply movement with a joystick like this;

`rb.velocity = new Vector3(move.x, move.y)* speed;`

The problem is that when a character walks around a sphere, they rotate, so the movement gets messed up, how do I make them move relative to the current rotation and not the world?

I'm new to unity and coding in general so showing example code would help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a one-liner:

`rb.veloxity = transform.rotation * move * speed;`

Multiplying a `Quaternion` rotation by a vector rotates the vector by that rotation.

Unity will also automatically promote a `Vector2` to a `Vector3` (or back), so we don't need to make a `new Vector3()` explicitly here.